# Average rasters based on their names in R

Tags: r, raster

I would like to average several rasters by months. The files are named as follows:

```
africa_arc.20160101

africa_arc.20160102

africa_arc.20160103
```

Here is my current code, its not grabbing the files by their names:

```
require(raster)
require(maptools)
require(rgdal)

iDir <- "D:/RainfallFTP_unzipped"
oDir <- "D:/RainfallFTP_unzipped_AVG"

yrLs <- c("2016", "2017")
mthLs <- c(paste0("0",1:9), 10:12)
dyLs <- seq(as.Date('2016-01-01'),as.Date('2017-12-31'),by = 1)
dLs <- format(dyLs,"%d")

for (yr in yrLs){
  for (mth in mthLs){ 

    r.stk <- stack(paste0(iDir, "/", "africa_arc.", yr, mth, dLs, ".tif", sep=""))

  }    

}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should always avoid (double) loops when possible.

Here's a simple solution, with only a couple of lines:

```
library (raster)

iDir <- "D:/RainfallFTP_unzipped/"

# list rasters in iDir
rs <- list.files(iDir,full.names = T)

# extract year-month and use lapply to grep and stack
r.stk <- lapply(sub('.+(\\d{6})\\d{2}','\\1',rs),function(x) stack(grep(x,rs,value = T)))
```

This will leave you with a list with each element being a stack of rasters for each year-month combination.

Please note that this assumes your filenames are as in your examples (so they end in the date without extension) and the rasters are located in `iDir`, not in any sub-directories of `iDir`.

If your rasters have a `tif` extension, as I think they have looking at your code, you just have to substitute the `sub` call within `lapply` to

```
sub('.+(\\d{6}).+tif$','\\1',rs)
```

to account for the file ending.